# View from ModelAndView vs View from ViewResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web

In Spring MVC, when request commes, `DispatcherServlet` specifies `HandlerMapping` that indicates which controller should process request. `Controller` processes request and returns model with specified `View`.

And I dont get what happens after that, when `ViewResolver` starts his work. If `View` is already specified by `Controller`, why there is a `ViewResolver` layer? What does it actually do? Shouldn't `View` been specified before or paraller with `Controller`? Or maybe `Controller` should trigger `ViewResolver` layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ViewResolver` maps view names to actual views.when you have for example:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

you tell spring in controller method when you return a string, add prefix and suffix to the return value and the load that view, lets say you have

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    return "home";
}
```

ViewResolver will take home and change it to `home.jsp` and will look at /WEB-INF/views/ to load `/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp`

Comment: So ViewResolver layer is triggered only, when you return a view name as String, and not a specified View?

Comment: indeed, in controller , each view must be translated in a way that spring can resolve it. This view may be pdf , JSON, html, jsp , xml and so. A String can not tell spring how to resolve those views without utilizing ViewResolver